# problem of bean injection RabbitTemplate in Junit

Tags: java, reactor-netty

I have small problems, injection of a bean
when I run in spring-boot everything works well but with Junit.
I have an example with RabbitTemplate
..............................................................................................................................................................

> ```
> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
> at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:125) ~[spring-test-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:108) ~[spring-test-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:118) ~[spring-test-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:83) ~[spring-test-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.SpringBootDependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(SpringBootDependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:44) ~[spring-boot-test-autoconfigure-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:246) ~[spring-test-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:227) [spring-test-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289) [spring-test-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
> at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
> at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:291) [spring-test-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:246) [spring-test-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:97) [spring-test-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
> at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
> at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
> at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
> at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
> at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
> at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61) [spring-test-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70) [spring-test-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
> at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
> at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:190) [spring-test-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
> at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:89) [.cp/:na]
> at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:41) [.cp/:na]
> at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:541) [.cp/:na]
> at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:763) [.cp/:na]
> at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:463) [.cp/:na]
> at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:209) [.cp/:na]
> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'rabbitManager': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'rabbitTemplate'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:596) ~[spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:90) ~[spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:374) ~[spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1411) ~[spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:592) ~[spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515) ~[spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320) ~[spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318) ~[spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:849) ~[spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:877) ~[spring-context-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:549) ~[spring-context-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:775) ~[spring-boot-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) ~[spring-boot-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:316) ~[spring-boot-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:127) ~[spring-boot-test-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:99) ~[spring-test-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:117) ~[spring-test-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
> ... 26 common frames omitted
> Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoMatchingBeanFound(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1654) ~[spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1213) ~[spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1167) ~[spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:593) ~[spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
> ... 44 common frames omitted
> ```

Code :

```
    public class NettyServerRun {

    @Autowired
    private IDeviceClient deviceClientComponent;
    @Autowired
    private ServiceDeviceServer service;

    @Autowired
    private RabbitManager mqService;

    private int port = 7650;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() throws InterruptedException {
        NioEventLoopGroup boosGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup();
        NioEventLoopGroup workerGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup();
        ServerBootstrap bootstrap = new ServerBootstrap();
        bootstrap.group(boosGroup, workerGroup);
        bootstrap.channel(NioServerSocketChannel.class);
        final EventExecutorGroup group = new DefaultEventExecutorGroup(1500); 
        bootstrap.childHandler(new ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel>() {
        @Override
        protected void initChannel(SocketChannel ch) throws Exception {
        ChannelPipeline pipeline = ch.pipeline();
        pipeline.addLast(workerGroup,new 
        RequestDecoderServer(deviceClientComponent)); 
        pipeline.addLast(workerGroup,new ResponseEncoderServer()); 
        pipeline.addLast(group,new AuthenticateHandler(service));
        pipeline.addLast(group,new CommandResponseHandler(service));
        pipeline.addLast(group,new DeviceDataHandler(mqService));
    }
        });
        ChannelFuture f = bootstrap.bind(port).sync();
        f.channel().closeFuture().sync();
    }


    @RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
    @DataJpaTest
    @Import(NettyServerRun.class)
    @AutoConfigureTestDatabase(replace=Replace.ANY)
    @ComponentScan("com.metier")
    public abstract class DeviceServerTest {

    @Autowired
    protected TestEntityManager entityManager;

    @Autowired
    protected ServiceDeviceServer service;

    @Autowired
    protected TestRestTemplate template;


    protected DeviceServerContext context;
    protected Gson gson;
    protected Nmea nmeaData;

    @Value("${spring.profiles.active}")
    private String activeProfile;


    protected void persistList(List<AbstractEntity> list) {
        list.forEach(entity -> entityManager.persist(entity));
    }

    public GpsCmdRsp buidGpsCmdRsp(Long gpsId) {
        GpsCmdRsp reference = new GpsCmdRsp();
        reference.setCommand("*TS01,188765,NAM#");
        reference.setCompletedAt(buildHier());
        reference.setGpsId(gpsId);
        reference.setResponse("*TS01,353836057694499,013809281017,NAM:ODO50- 
        BLE#");
        reference.setSuccess(false);
        return reference;
     }
 }


  public class DeviceDataHandlerTest extends DeviceServerTest {

    @Autowired
    private NettyServerRun nettyServerRun;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {

    }

    @Test
    public void channelReadDeviceExistTest() {
        String[] trame = {
                "*TS01,351579056605817,003410140618,GPS:3;N46.758156;W71.134046;6;0;0.96,STT:c003;8001,MGR:957975,SAT:43;40;39#" };
        EmbeddedChannel channel = new EmbeddedChannel(new DeviceDataHandler());
        boolean ok = channel.writeInbound(trame);
        assertThat(ok).isTrue();

    }

}
```

Comment: Mind wrapping that big stacktrace in a code block?  And have you tried using @SpringBootTest annotation on your test class?

Comment: This is not related to Reactor Netty